# Basic4Android How change background Color of AutoCompleteEditText

Tags: autocompletetextview, basic4android

it`s really Weird that that there is no option or setting for set background Color of AutoCompleteEditText in **BASIC4Android**

my app have a white theme and design , so i set the AutoCompleteEditText edit-box background color to white and then set color text to black !

now when i compile it after type something to see the items in drop down , the background color of drop down is dark gray ( not nice for a white theme) and worse of this making colors of editbox text to black affect on color of texts in drop down items too and made them black

so it`s ugly and really hard to Read

**in Eclipse i saw some xml code to To define and change the default colors of these items but in B4A i dont have any clue**

i really need help please help

## *[ how change background color of items in B4A AutoCompleteEditText ]*

Comment: no one have any Clue ??!  :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi this should work.

Dim a As AutoCompleteEditText

a.Color = Colors.Black